# can anyone recommend a php keyword density code?

Tags: php, keyword

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is Keyword Density and how to create a script in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/819166/what-is-keyword-density-and-how-to-create-a-script-in-php)

Can anyone recommend a good implementation of php code which calculates keyword density in a string?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/819166/1220966

Comment: Do checks before you post a questions. Do your homework :) Good Q. though...

Answer (score -2):

This is a great question Yoav, I think there are some good resources for this in google free projects I saw, and I also saw this service that gives good results:
http://www.webconfs.com/keyword-density-checker.php